# Calling find_package more than once not working

Tags: c++, c, cmake, openssl

I have a locally build openssl that I am linking to statically. In one of my cmake targets I am doing the following and it is working fine.

```
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl/include)
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL 1.1.1 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

I now have another target that needs openssl, so i added this same snippet to that CMakeLists.txt file too. On a fresh cmake configure (no CMakeCache.txt), it complains for the second target:

> Could NOT find OpenSSL...blah blah

However, if I try to configure a second time, it finds it fine.

What is going on here? Is there a better way of doing this?

**Edit to add minimal example:**

CMakeLists.txt (root)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)

project (test)

add_subdirectory(test1)
add_subdirectory(test2)
```

CMakeLists.txt under test1 and test2 (identical)

```
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../deps/ssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../deps/ssl/include)
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL 1.1.1 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

The result is

```
-- Found OpenSSL: /var/dev/deps/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a (found suitable exact version "1.1.1g")  
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required
  is exact version "1.1.1")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:459 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  test2/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

As you can see the first one is found, hence the path is correct.

Comment: It is difficult to say what is going wrong with your another target without viewing the **code**. E.g. if your other `CMakeLists.txt` uses `project()` call, then it changes the value of [PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) variable, so value of `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR` variable becomes wrong. Please, add the code (in form of [mcve]) into the question post.

Comment: Added example in the post

Comment: Setting variable `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` is actually a wrong way to work with `find_package(OpenSSL)`. Try to remove the line `set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ...)` and check again.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`find_package` itself would populate variables (cache entries) like `OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OPENSSL_DIR` etc. hence I don't see the need for

```
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl/include)
```

If you intend to suggest some paths/hints (which in this case seems to be `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl`) then I would suggest `PATHS` or `HINTS` argument in `find_package`. For instance:

```
find_package(OpenSSL 1.1.1 EXACT REQUIRED
             HINTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl 
                   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/ssl/include
)
```

If the `find_package` succeeds (the result of which is stored in `OpenSSL_FOUND`), you could link the libraries to the target as:

```
if (NOT OpenSSL_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ERROR: OpenSSL package not found.")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${YOUR_TARGET_HERE} ${OpenSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(${YOUR_TARGET_HERE} PUBLIC ${OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

You would need to put the `find_package` command only in the "root" CMakeLists.txt and just use the cache variable (like `OpenSSL_LIBRARIES` and `OpenSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS`) in the child CMakeList.txt files where you want to link them to the targets.

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: The answer is quite misleading. "I don't see the need for ... `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`" - That variable is "official" way for hinting `find_package()`, so setting it perfectly valid. See documentation for [FindOpenSSL module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html#hints). As opposite, `HINTS` option to the `find_package` does the **different things**. E.g., it unconditionally switches [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) to the CONFIG mode, which requires existence of the OpenSSL **config file**.

Answer (score 0):

As I encountered the exact same problem, I believe the answer is what @Tsyvarev commented on the question:

> Setting variable OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR is actually a wrong way to work with find_package(OpenSSL). Try to remove the line set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ...) and check again

I also incorrectly had that set.